# How can I start a function in a new tab using a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, function, firefox, tabs, bookmarklet

This is my first time taking a shot at JavaScript, so excuse me if it seems a bit rough.

This website http://www.keepvid.com/ provides a bookmark with JavaScript that allows you to download video off of YouTube and other media sites by clicking on it when on the media page. However, I found that instead of opening the download page in a new tab, it opens it in the current one, interrupting the media (probably to encourage you to buy their pro version).

Seeing it as a chance to try out JavaScript (as I have only used bookmarklets before), I have been searching for answers, but the ones I found seem to only have worked with older versions of the website, as the JavaScript seems updated.

I have been trying to make a bookmarklet that opens a new page, and then loads the download page for the media.

The first code I encountered as a solution was: `javascript:void(window.open('http://keepvid.com/?url='+escape(window.location)));`

But this didn't work, which was when I noticed that the bookmarklet's final URL added `&bm=y` to the end of the URL, so I edited it to:
`javascript:void(window.open('http://keepvid.com/?url='+escape(window.location)+'&bm=y'));`

I then looked at the bookmarklet's original code::
`javascript:
(a%20=%20(b%20=%20document).createElement('script')).src%20=%20'http://keepvid.com/js/bm.js',%20b.body.appendChild(a);void(0);`

and realized that it was calling on an external script (I believe) and that it would have to stay intact.

And from their I have been trying various methods at getting this to work, and so far, this is what I have:
`javascript:void(window.open(window.location));void((a%20=%20(b%20=%20document).createElement('script')).src%20=%20'http://keepvid.com/js/bm.js',%20b.body.appendChild(a));`

This script opens a new tab, but the new tab will only be a copy of the YouTube video, and the original tab will load the download page, which still interrupts the media, rendering my work useless, if slightly more convenient.

I have been trying every way I can, but it seems like I can't have a second script in the same bookmarklet without it pointing to the original tab it was called in.

So, I have been wondering what it is I need to do in order to:
1. Create a new tab
2. Have the new tab load the download page (instead of the original)
3. Leave the original tab alone and use it only to capture the window.location

If this is impossible to do, is their a way to have a bookmarklet in the toolbox that makes a copy of the original page and then points to a bookmarklet in the bookmarks menu that contains the redirect to the download page?

Comment: Don't have a technical solution for you, but as far as a better bookmarklet for downloading videos, you may want to check out this: http://deturl.com/bookmarklet-to-directly-download-videos-from-youtube.asp

Comment: Another comment. Your 1st bookmarklet worked for me when I tested on YouTube with Firefox. Please note that in Firefox you can not paste bookmarklet code into the URL for testing the way you used to be able to do. You must enter it into an actual bookmark first. In Chrome you can only do it if you manually type "javascript:" first. If you try to paste the bookmarklet code, the "javascript:" part will be removed.

Comment: First off, I just checked out the link you gave me, and that seems like a very good bookmarklet to download YouTube videos. But at the moment, I really just want to solve this problem to see what I can do with JavaScript. Second, just to clarify, whenever I made an edit to the JavaScript, I would paste it into the bookmark, not the URL. And about the first bookmarklet working, I'll throw you the picture comparison I gave "mplungjan". [(Picture of KeepVid Code)](http://i.imgur.com/77g5f.png) | [(Picture of my code)](http://i.imgur.com/GuxYo.png). Notice the difference in the list of downloads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy this text: http://keepvid.com/js/bm.js

Change

```
<form method='post'
```

to

```
<form method='post' target='_blank'
```

You can host the file on your own server and append the script in the same manner as the original bookmarklet, or you can compress the code into a stand alone bookmarklet like this

```
javascript:eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return%20r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new%20RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return%20p}('o%20i(a,b,c){N{7%20u=a.v(b);7%20w=u[1].v(c);x%20w[0]}O(P){x\'\'}}o%20p(){7%20q=d.Q("R");q.9="<z%20S=\'T\'%20U=\'V\'%20W=\'r://A.g/?B="+C(h.j)+"&X=y\'%20Y=\'D\'><k%20l=\'s\'%20t=\'Z\'%20m=\'"+8+"\'%20/><k%20l=\'s\'%20t=\'2\'%20m=\'"+2+"\'%20/><k%20l=\'s\'%20t=\'5\'%20m=\'"+5+"\'%20/><k%2010=\'11-12-E%20F-G-13%20F-G-14\'%20l=\'H\'%20m=\'15%2016%2017\'%20/></z>";d.e.19(q);h.1a["D"].H()}7%20d=h;6(d.j.I.1b(/J.g/i)){7%208=i(d.e.9,\';8=\',\'&\');6(8==\'\')8=i(d.e.9,\'"8":%20"\',\'"\');7%202=i(d.e.9,\'2"%201c="\',\'"\');6(2==\'\')2=i(d.e.9,\'1d"%202="\',\'"\');7%205=i(d.e.9,\'n=\',\'&\');6(5==\'\')5=i(3.f,\'n":%20"\',\'"\').K("\\\\/","/");6(5==\'\'){7%203=1e;6(!3&&1f%20L!=\'1g\'){3=E%20L()}3.1h("1i","r://1j.J.g/1k?8="+8+"&5=18",1l);3.1m=o(){6(3.1n==4){2=i(3.f,\'&2=\',\'&\');6(2==\'\')2=i(3.f,\'2=\',\'&\');5=i(3.f,\'n=\',\'&\');6(5==\'\')5=i(3.f,\'n":%20"\',\'"\').K("\\\\/","/");p()}};3.1o()}M{p()}}M{h.j.I=\'r://A.g/?B=\'+C(1p.j)}',62,88,'||title|kvajax||fmt|if|var|video_id|innerHTML|||||body|responseText|com|document||location|input|type|value|fmt_stream_map|function|finishkv|gd|http|hidden|name|a1|split|a2|return||form|keepvid|url|escape|kvdl|new|yt|uix|submit|href|youtube|replace|XMLHttpRequest|else|try|catch|err|createElement|div|method|post|target|blank|action|bm|id|vid|class|master|sprite|button|tooltip|Download|with|KeepVid||appendChild|forms|match|content|ltr|false|typeof|undefined|open|GET|www|get_video_info|true|onreadystatechange|readyState|send|window'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

I packed it using this: http://javascriptcompressor.com/

For treating non-youtube sites in the same manner, also change

```
document.location.href='http://keepvid.com/?url='+escape(window.location);
```

to

```
window.open('http://keepvid.com/?url='+escape(window.location));
```

Comment: Thank you, the bookmarklet code you provided works perfectly. However, since this is all a practice for me to learn more about how JavaScript works, would you mind explaining how you were able to compress the code into a bookmarklet?

Comment: Using the link that I gave. There was one missing semicolon that I had to add though.

Answer (score 3):

This question is a bit old, but my little bookmarklet to open dict.cc in a new tab fits perfectly to the question title.

```
javascript:(function(){window.open("http://www.dict.cc/?s="+encodeURIComponent(prompt("Enter word to look for:")))})();
```

I'm not sure what the wrapper function does, but without it, the current tab will get cleared.

Src: https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/javascript-bookmarklet-basics/

Comment: Why the overhead of an anonymous function? Why not just `javascript:window.open("http://www.dict.cc/?s="+encodeURIComponent(prompt("Enter word to look for:")));`?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, without it the current tab would get cleared. At least at time of writing, 8 years ago. I just checked, that is still the case with Firefox 111.0.1. The current tab would get overwritten with [object Window].

Comment: @Hendrick Interesting - that doesn't seem to happen in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

> The first code I encountered as a solution was:
>   javascript:void(window.open('http://keepvid.com/?url='+escape(window.location)));
>
> But this didn't work

Did not work in what way? If the browser is blocking popups, you will not succeed.
If it does not, that method should work.

Here is a possible other method - still not guaranteed to work any better

You need to store a script on your server.
The script is loaded into the current window using

```
(function() {var scr=document.createElement('script');scr.src='http://www.yourserver.com/yourserverprocess.php?loc=escape(window.location.href;document.getElementByTagname('head')[0].appendChild(scr); })();
```

then on your server you can return (assuming php)

```
header("content-type: text/javascript");
echo "window.open('http://yourserver.com/convert.php?loc=".$_GET["loc"],'_blank')";
```

Comment: The code I used opened a new tab and loaded the download page: (keepvid.com/?url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/…). However, this method did not show the available downloads on the loaded page. The bookmarklet from KeepVid.com loaded the download page, and then showed a list of available downloads to choose from (regarding quality of video). Here is a picture comparison to make it a little more clear. [(Picture of KeepVid Code)](http://i.imgur.com/77g5f.png) | [(Picture of my Code)](http://i.imgur.com/GuxYo.png) Notice the same URL with different results.

Comment: Ah, I did not realise you actually meant to use the keepvid and not use your own. - that could be down to many reasons. Perhaps some parameter was set in the first script that you did not catch. It is too late for me to look now - perhaps you can tell me what the end result is you are looking for? Reverse engineering or what?

Comment: This is just a practice for me to get introduced to JavaScript. The result I am looking for is for the function to run in the new tab that is created instead of the first tab that the bookmark is started in. So, if I hosted "Script 1" on a server, gave it the commands to open a duplicate tab, then had it end and load "Script 2", which would contain the KeepVid code, would this load the download page in the second tab instead of the first, since it was started in the second tab? So would this work - Tab 1 loads Script 1; Script 1 creates Tab 2; Tab 2 loads Script 2; Script 2 loads Download Page